# How to compare Enum value with u32

Tags: visual-studio-code, unix, rust

I have code something like this.

```
#[derive(PartialEq)]
enum FALUDA {
    Juice,
    Ice,
}

let a: u32 = 0;

if a == FALUDA::Juice {
 //Yay
}
```

If I try this code I am getting below error.

```
78 |     if a                 == FALUDA::Juice {
   |        --------             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `u32`, found `FALUDA`
   |        |
   |        expected because this is `u32`
```

I dont want to cast.

Comment: what does this have to do with VS Code?

Comment: **Why** don't you want to cast?

Answer (score 1):

You need to *cast* the enum value to `u32` (the type of `a`).

Here is a complete example:

```
#[derive(PartialEq)]
enum FALUDA {
    Juice,
    Ice,
}

fn main() {
    let a: u32 = 0;
    if a == FALUDA::Juice as u32 {
        print!("Juicy")
    }
}
```

For simple cases casting really is all one should need. But if you need to do a lot of conversions from/to enum values, you might consider using a crate, such as [strum_macros](https://docs.rs/strum_macros).

Comment: No, I dont want to cast

Comment: @optimusprime I updated my answer to reflect your update. My initial answer was essentially the answer to your question "How to compare Enum value with u32". But when you then say that you don't want to cast, It would be useful to explain why. Casting is there for a reason and it's the standard way to convert between enum and integer values (in order to, for example, compare them, as is your case).

Comment: Still you are casting in if condition na. The code that you kept is same as mine except that 'as'

Comment: Can we achieve something with match?

Comment: You can write a `Faluda::from_u32` with a match to give you a `Option<Faluda>` back, and you can do `Faluda::from_u32(a) == Some(Faluda::Juice)`

Comment: inside that from_u32 I need to keep match or something again.

Answer (score 0):

-- *Can we achieve something with match?*

Yes, you can implement `PartialEq<FALUDA>` for `u32`:

```rust
#[derive(PartialEq)]
enum FALUDA {
    Juice,
    Ice,
}

impl PartialEq<FALUDA> for u32 {
    fn eq(&self, rhs: &FALUDA) -> bool {
        match rhs {
            FALUDA::Juice => self == &0,
            FALUDA::Ice => self == &1,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a: u32 = 0;

    if a == FALUDA::Juice {
        println!("Yay");
    }
}
```

But this may prove unstable if you'd decide to change the order of `FALUDA`'s variants.